# What is DataContractTranslator?

Tags: wcf

Can anyone please explain me what is DataContractTranslstor and what's it's use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take a look at this write up](http://www.babel-lutefisk.net/2008/02/wcf-data-contract-translation.html)

Comment: It is not always the case that a data contract is translated to and from a business object. Some services don't even use business objects.